# Find radical of hermitian form $\langle , \rangle _A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine the radical of the hermitian form $\langle , \rangle _A$ over the field $\mathbb{C}^3$, where $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i & -i \\ i & 2 & 1 \\ i & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Would it be sufficient to calulate the kernel of the matrix $A$ or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you define $\langle , \rangle _A$ as $\langle \vec x , \vec y \rangle _A = \vec x^TA\overline{\vec y}  $. I emphasize this as it is sometimes (particularly in physics) defined as $\langle \vec x , \vec y \rangle _A = \vec x^HA\vec y$.

The (left) radical is defined as $L_A=\{\vec x \in \mathbb C^3 | (\forall \vec y \in \mathbb C^3)\langle \vec x, \vec y \rangle = \overline {\langle \vec y, \vec x \rangle} = \overline {\vec y^TA} \vec x=0  \}$. This means that $\overline{A}{\vec x}=0$. Therefore, we are looking for $\ker{\overline{A}} $.

The right radical $R_A=\{\vec y \in \mathbb C^3 | (\forall \vec x \in \mathbb C^3)\langle \vec x, \vec y \rangle = \vec x^T A \overline {\vec y} =0  \}=L_A$ in the case of hermitian form.

Comment: So basically we are looking for $\ker{A}$ since it is already transposed and conjugated because it is the matrix associated to a hermitian form, right?

Comment: Not really. We are looking for $\ker{\overline{A}}=\ker{A^T}$. However, you may be correct, depending on your definition of the matrix of hermitian form. I edited my answer.

Comment: Well, we defined the radical of a hermitian form as: $\langle , \rangle$ hermitian form, $V^\perp = \{ v \in V \mid \forall w \in V : \langle v,w \rangle = 0 \}$, from a lemma follows that the kernel is equal to $V^\perp = 0$. Another lemma states that $\langle , \rangle _A$ hermitian $\Leftrightarrow A = \overline{A}^t$.

Comment: 1.) Our notions of the radical correspond. 2.) The radical can't be equal to an equation, an expression rather. 3.) Your second lemma only tells you that $A$ is indeed a matrix of a hermitian form. What I meant is the answer depends on how you defined the matrix of hermitian form. See my edit.

Comment: alright I will try to calculate the $\ker{A^t}$ then.

Comment: There are several errors. How did you get from the second to the third matrix? Notice that if you multiply the last row by $i$, you get the first row.

Comment: My calculation was wrong you're right, I was confused. Here is the updated $$\ker{A^t} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i & i \\ -i & 2 & 2 \\ -i & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i & i \\ -i & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix} -i & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0$$ How to extract the information for the $\ker$ out of that? (second step again multiplied the second row with $i$)

Comment: Just find the one vector by which when you multiply the matrix from the right you get the zero vector. The kernel is all the multiples of the vector.